# Row aggregation of count-distinct measure

Tags: ssas, aggregate

I have a fairly simple project set up to demonstrate what I want here. Here's the data:

**Group**

```
ID  Name
 1  Group 1
 2  Group 2
 3  Group 3
```

**Person**

```
ID  GroupID  Age  Name
 1        1   18  John
 2        1   21  Stephen
 3        1   18  Kate
 4        2   18  Mary
 5        2   19  Joseph
 6        2   19  Michael
 7        3   21  David
 8        3   22  Kevin
 9        3   21  Julian
```

I have 1 measure in my cube called **Person Count** which is a `Distinct count` on **Person ID**
I have set up each non-ID column in the dimensions as attributes (Age, Person Name, Group).

When I process and browse the cube in Business Intelligence Development Studio, I get the following result set:

[image: Actual Results]

But what I actually want here are the rows for Age to aggregate up the count of the Person Count together, so here it should show **2** and only one row for **18**.

[image: Required Results]

Is this possible (and how)?

Comment: I have a feeling I can implement this somehow with a measure expression, but I'm not entirely sure what I need to do.

Comment: .. that's a negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a problem with the way I set up the Age attribute for the dimension.
I had:
**KeyColumns** = `Person.ID`
**ValueColumn** = `Person.Age`.

I don't know why I did this, but the solution is to delete the content of **ValueColumn** and set the **KeyColumns** to `Person.Age` again.

I now get the following result:

[image: Final result]

Everything else is the same for the project; this was the only change and is exactly what I wanted. If I get any issues with it I will keep this post updated for anyone else who may run into this in the future.